# Catch a variable from another PHP page

Tags: variables, try-catch, show

Let's assume I'm working with a variable called "$name" in a page called Action.php.

This variable contains the value of a field of a form.


So the user comes to let's say "contact.html", fills the form (action="Action.php"), and then Action.php say thanks to the user with a simple echo when the user sends the form.


Okay, now, if I don't have access to the source of the PHP file, how could I proceed to show the value of the variable $name?

Comment: I don't understand. You mean if Action.php contain $name but It doesn't echo anything but you want to echo $name?

Comment: Well, Action.php doesn't show $name, it just use it to proceed with some comparisons and then to send an email containing the value of the variable, but the client does not see anything of this, he just see "Tahnk you, your message was sent!".
But I would like, as a client, to show the value of the variable $name, with maybe some injected code in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the contents of the variable in a hidden field on the form to the next php page which picks it up with a request as you would any other form field.